# Поведение SwipeToRefresh при null RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

Есть `RecyclerView` и `SwipeToRefresh`.
Когда загружаются данные,то включается loader `SwipeToRefresh`, после можно свайпать вниз и анимация будет проигрываться. Но, если запустить приложение без интернет-соединения, придет пустой массив, и свайп уже не тянется, его просто нет. На пару секунд появляется, когда пытается в первый раз подтянуть данные. Как сделать, чтобы можно было его тянуть при пустом массиве, позже там будет обновления код.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение: проверить данные перед тем как пришли, если null, то отключать recyclerView `recyclerView.visibility = View.GONE`